# SeqNo Conflict and Data Too Large error elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

*Issue elastic Data Too Large* :

```
{
    "statusCode": 429,
    "message": "search_phase_execution_exception\n\tCaused by:\n\t\tcircuit_breaking_exception: [parent] Data too large, data for [indices:data/read/search[phase/query+fetch/scroll]] would be [2057263950/1.9gb], which is larger than the limit of [2040109465/1.8gb], real usage: [2057263808/1.9gb], new bytes reserved: [142/142b], usages [eql_sequence=0/0b, fielddata=8190/7.9kb, request=0/0b, inflight_requests=59869398/57mb, model_inference=0/0b]\n\tRoot causes:\n\t\tcircuit_breaking_exception: [parent] Data too large, data for [indices:data/read/search[phase/query+fetch/scroll]] would be [2057263950/1.9gb], which is larger than the limit of [2040109465/1.8gb], real usage: [2057263808/1.9gb], new bytes reserved: [142/142b], usages [eql_sequence=0/0b, fielddata=8190/7.9kb, request=0/0b, inflight_requests=59869398/57mb, model_inference=0/0b]"
}
```

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-does-this-error-mean-data-too-large-data-for-transport-request/209345

*Issue seqNo Conflict* :

```
{"statusCode":409,"message":"{\"took\":4004,\"timed_out\":false,\"total\":223,\"updated\":0,\"deleted\":0,\"batches\":1,\"version_conflicts\":223,\"noops\":0,\"retries\":{\"bulk\":0,\"search\":0},\"throttled_millis\":0,\"requests_per_second\":-1,\"throttled_until_millis\":0,\"failures\":[{\"index\":\"daep-dev-log-login\",\"id\":\"e5c61871-9f9a-4ad6-b626-1d1010a6ef1d\",\"cause\":{\"type\":\"version_conflict_engine_exception\",\"reason\":\"[e5c61871-9f9a-4ad6-b626-1d1010a6ef1d]: version conflict, required seqNo [91523], primary term [50]. current document has seqNo [91746] and primary term }]}
```

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/version-conflict-engine-exception-seqno-question/272930
- Anybody here ever got this error?
  I want to solve this problem